# Prevent user system setting for time and date string processing

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to load datetime and time string in process

```
DateTime strTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have several places to process date time string, from dateTimePicker:

```
 UseDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd");
```

with writing and then loading from the file:

```
 dateTimePicker3.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(DB, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it works proper with english, but not sure how to prevent if user have different setting like  chinese or russian, in this case I got:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I can prevent input with different punctuation with replace  `"/"`,  `"."`, and remove all words from string, but in this case I'm not sure how to figure out proper way.

For example, in debug I see `strTime` with russian `"апреля 10, 2017 - понедельник"` string, but how to change it to correct readable  date without words. I can't process it with regular expression, because in result I can get something like `102017` or at least `10.20.17` but not `10 April of 2017` which must be `10.04.2017` or `10/04/2017` or `10-04-2017` or even in different order `4/10/2017` etc

Comment: maybe this can help http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp#DtFormatsInput

Comment: where does your input comes from ? can you make an editmask that only allows one format or does it come from an external source where you cant do anything about it ?

Comment: @GuidoG Hello, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using DateTime.ParseExact and this means that the format mask that you provide should match exactly what you are passing as string to be converted to a datetime.

In case of a russian conversion of that string ("апреля 10, 2017 - понедельник") you should provide a mask of this type with the appropriate CultureInfo

```
 "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd"
```

Now, if you have different formats to parse you could pass, as second parameter to ParseExact an array of string formats like this one

```
 string[] formats = new string[] 
 {
    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd"
 };

 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru");
 DateTime strTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to find solution to change any different culture input to Englesh Culture and yyyy-M-d

Comment: But how do you know the input culture if it is not the standard set on the locale of your system? Do you have something that tells you what is the culture of the input string?

Comment: But what is not clear from your question is if you have a special application that needs to handle different cultures on the same PC. Usually, if your winforms app runs on a Russian  computer then the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture will be set to Russian, while in Italy it will be Italian and so on. A single computer uses the locale settings from the OS unless you have some other needs.

Comment: The problem is that you call ToString() when you have a perfect valid date in the Value property. You are converting the date to a string then why do you want to convert it back to a DateTime?. Keep it as a DateTime and _only_ when you need to display it use the ToString() to properly format it. A DateTime has no format by itself, it is the way you want to display it that requires a _format_

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do any string operation to parse a `string` to a `DateTime`, just the correct CultureInfo and format string. Using your example string, the way to parse it would be something like:

```
string strTime = "апреля 10, 2017 - понедельник";
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
DateTime dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime, "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd", ci);
```

As you see, with the appropiate culture and the format string, the date gets parsed correctly.

BTW, is worth noticing that with `ParseExact` you can have as many format strings as you want, just using `string[]`:

```
string[] formats = new string[] 
{
     "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd", "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy"
};
DateTime dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(strTime, formats, ci);
```

Comment: so he has to know which culture info to use. What if its mixed in his input ?

Comment: No, you don't need to know it. As OP is using winforms, just using `CurrentCulture` would make the `ParseExact` work, as long the date string has the appropiate format

Comment: this makes this answer complete +1

Comment: @Pikoh Yes this way I can change it to different, but I'm trying to find the way  to change any different culture input to Englesh Culture  yyyy-M-d